# Refactor react native component ComponentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native

*Edit - Sorry I should have been more clearer (heavy New Year I think :/), I'm trying to refactor this from a State components to a functional one with Hooks. I can do all except I'm not sure where to put the stuff in ComponentWillMount in a functional, and assumed I should useEffect, but I can't get it to work!

I've been playing around with React Native and using little bits from here and there and managed to make a little card that flips on tap.

I'm usually ok a refactoring components to functional but I'm struggling to get this one working - I'm not sure what to do with the ComponentsWillMount. I tried putting it in a useEffect, but no go :/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Animated, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Text } from 'react-native';
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';

export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            animatedValue: new Animated.Value(0),
        }
    }

  flipCard() {
    if (this.value >= 90) {
      Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
        toValue: 0,
        friction: 8,
        tension: 10
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
        toValue: 180,
        friction: 8,
        tension: 10
      }).start();
    }
  }

    componentWillMount() {

        // Flipcard animation

        this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
        this.value = 0;
        this.animatedValue.addListener(({ value }) => {
            this.value = value;
        })
        this.frontInterpolate = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 180],
            outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
        })
        this.backInterpolate = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 180],
            outputRange: ['180deg', '360deg']
        })
        this.frontOpacity = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [89, 90],
        outputRange: [1, 0]
        });

        this.backOpacity = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [89, 90],
        outputRange: [0, 1]
        });

        this.elevationFront = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 25],
          outputRange: [10, 0]
          })

        this.elevationBack = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [155, 180],
          outputRange: [0, 10]
          })
    }

  render() {

        const frontAnimatedStyle = {
        transform: [{ rotateY: this.frontInterpolate}]
        }
        const backAnimatedStyle = {
        transform: [{ rotateY: this.backInterpolate }]
        }
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.flipCard()} >
          <View>
                <Animated.View style={[frontAnimatedStyle, styles.paperFront,{elevation: this.elevationFront}, {opacity: this.frontOpacity}]}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 20,paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, color: 'black',lineHeight: 20}}>
                    Title Front - <Text style={{fontSize: 8}}>KPI</Text>
                  </Text>
                    <View style={{position: "absolute", paddingTop: 3, right: 8}}>
                      <TabBarIcon style={{color: "black"}} name={"md-more"} />
                    </View>
                </Animated.View>

                <Animated.View style={[backAnimatedStyle, styles.paperBack, {elevation: this.elevationBack}, {opacity: this.backOpacity}]}>
                  <Text>Back title</Text>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    paperFront : {
      marginHorizontal: 15,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      minHeight: 200,
      borderRadius: 5,
      marginBottom: 15,

    },
    paperBack : {
      top: -215,
      marginHorizontal: 15,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      minHeight: 200,
      borderRadius: 5,
      marginBottom: 15,
    }
});
```

Comment: useEffect  Designed for the hooks but you use in the component

Comment: Try loading codes in 'componentWillMount' to 'constructor'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with empty array as second parameter? This will run only once.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Your code here
}, []);
```